# IllegalStateException with URL in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm developing a mobile application and I'm using it to fetch data from my API using `AsyncTask`. The problem is, I'm receiving following exception as the app tries to connect to the API.

```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be
> null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null,
> path=api.mywebsite.net/test
```

I think it has something to do with the absence of `http://` in my URL but even when I add that, it shows above exception.
This is how I'm creating a HTTP request:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("api.mywebsite.net/test");    
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Appreciate your help.

**Update**: the original URL returns valid `json` when called from a browser or accessed via one of the REST testing tools I'm using. Upon further inspection of the `request` headers through developer's tool by Chrome, I see that it indeed has `http://` in the Request URL section of the request.

Comment: Would the downvoter elaborate their reason!?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add `http://` or `https://` to your `HttpGet`?

Comment: @zozelfelfo I did try and add `http://` but it returned the same exception. I've mentioned that in the question, as well. "I think it has something to do with the absence of http:// in my URL but even when I add that, it shows above exception."

Comment: If it is some rest based services, try checking from rest clients available in net.

Comment: It is my own REST service and the test function is working properly on browser and on REST clients like Postman.

Comment: I don't think this makes any change but try using URI while creating HttpGet instance; new HttpGet(new URI("http://api.mywebsite.net/test"));

Comment: @aegean Let me try that.

Comment: Did that along with a surrounding try-catch block but it didn't work, as well.

Comment: I'm not using HttpPost, I'm using HttpGet

Answer (score 1):

I think this needs to be changed :

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.api.mywebsite.net/test");
```

Comment: Did that. Same exception is occurring

Comment: @BasitSaeed Usually it should work. Im unable to access "api.mywebsite.net/test". Is it on you local environment?

Comment: It is not the real URI. The actual one is api.fuelupapp.net/test

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set
>   in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=api.fuelupapp.net/test

To solve this problem you must add `http://` prefix to url.

Also if you do network operations on the ui thread you'll get `Exception on NetworkTask:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

I've just tried your case with code below and it works. `new NetworkTask().execute();`

```
private static class NetworkTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse> {

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.fuelupapp.net/test");
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("NetworkTask", "Exception on NetworkTask:" + e);
        }
        return httpResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
        super.onPostExecute(httpResponse);

        if(httpResponse != null) {
            Log.d("NetworkTask", "NetworkTask response received");
        } else {
            Log.d("NetworkTask", "NetworkTask error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was my own fault. I didn't enable `INTERNET` permission in `AndroidManifest` and sneaky Android didn't show me THAT as an error.

Anyway, make sure you do `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` enabled in your Manifest file.